# convert multi-value Map<String, Object [ ]> to json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, iteration

I have a `Map<String, List<Object>>` and i want to convert it to `JSON`.

Here is what I have: 
**Point 1:** Declaring variables

```
var map = new Map(), //map
jsonObject= {}, // oject that needs to be converted to JSON
value1 = { topic: "someText1", status: "0", action: "1", comment: "someComment1" }, // values of Map
value2 = { topic: "someText2", status: "0", action: "0", comment: "someComment2" },
value3 = { topic: "someText3", status: "1", action: "1", comment: "someComment3" };
```

**Point 2:** function to populate multi-value map

```
function populateMap(map, k, v) {
    map[k] = map[k] || [];
    map[k].push(v);
}
```

**Point 3:** populating Map 
*// key of map is concatenation of various attributes from web page, separated by **|***

```
populateMap(map, 'release|attachment|license1', value1);
populateMap(map, 'release|attachment|license1', value2);
populateMap(map, 'release1|attachment1|license1', value1);
populateMap(map, 'release1|attachment1|license2', value2);
populateMap(map, 'release1|attachment1|license3', value3);
populateMap(map, 'release2|attachment2|license2', value1);
populateMap(map, 'release2|attachment2|license2', value2);
```

**Point 4:** iterating map and populating jsonObject

```
for (var i in map) {
    var keys = i.split('|'), // splitting keys based on |
    last = keys.pop(),
    values = map[i];
    values.forEach(function (item, index) {
        keys.reduce((r, a) => r[a] = r[a] || {}, jsonObject)[last] = item;
    });
}
```

**Point 5:** current output (jsonObject printed on console)

```
{
  "release": {
    "attachment": {
      "license1": "[Object]"
    }
  },
  "release1": {
    "attachment1": {
      "license1": "[Object]",
      "license2": "[Object]",
      "license3": "[Object]"
    }
  },
  "release2": {
    "attachment2": {
      "license2": "[Object]"
    }
  }
}
```

**Point 6:** expected output (jsonObject)

```
{
  "release": {
    "attachment": {
      "license1": "[Object, Object]" // expecting array of objects here ^^
    }
  },
  "release1": {
    "attachment1": {
      "license1": "[Object]",
      "license2": "[Object]",
      "license3": "[Object]"
    }
  },
  "release2": {
    "attachment2": {
      "license2": "[Object, Object]"
    }
  }
}
```

^^ Since map is having array of objects for that key, So i want to have array of objects in `jsonObject`.

Can someone help me with tweak needs to be done in `map` traversal in **Point 4** to obtain expected result?

Comment: By `List`, do you mean `Array`?

Comment: @Ry- Yeah. It is array. sorry for the error in Title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use methods like `.set`, `.get`, `.has`, and `.delete` to interact with `Map`; setting its elements as properties is incorrect.

```
function populateMap(map, k, v) {
    let values = map.get(k);

    if (values === undefined) {
        map.set(k, values = []);
    }

    values.push(v);
}
```

Then iterating over the map looks like this:

```
const jsonObject = {};

for (const [key, values] of map) {
    setPath(jsonObject, key.split('|'), values);
}
```

and your `setPath` implementation stays pretty much the same:

```
function setPath(obj, [...keys], item) {
    const last = keys.pop();
    keys.reduce((r, a) => r[a] = r[a] || {}, obj)[last] = item;
}
```

In toto:

```js
function populateMap(map, k, v) {
    let values = map.get(k);

    if (values === undefined) {
        map.set(k, values = []);
    }

    values.push(v);
}

function setPath(obj, [...keys], item) {
    const last = keys.pop();
    keys.reduce((r, a) => r[a] = r[a] || {}, obj)[last] = item;
}

const map = new Map();

populateMap(map, 'release|attachment|license1', 'value1');
populateMap(map, 'release|attachment|license1', 'value2');
populateMap(map, 'release1|attachment1|license1', 'value1');
populateMap(map, 'release1|attachment1|license2', 'value2');
populateMap(map, 'release1|attachment1|license3', 'value3');
populateMap(map, 'release2|attachment2|license2', 'value1');
populateMap(map, 'release2|attachment2|license2', 'value2');

const jsonObject = {};

for (const [key, values] of map) {
    setPath(jsonObject, key.split('|'), values);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
```

Comment: Thanks much. I am very new to JavaScript. started learning last week. So i know very little about JS and it's built in functions

Answer (score 0):

you can use an object mapper to parse your multivalue map to your object or JSON

`new ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestValue.toSingleValueMap())`