# convert Map<String, Object> to json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a `Map<String, Object>` and I want to convert it to `JSON`.

Here is what I have: 
**Point 1:** Declaring variables

```
var map = new Map(), //map
jsonObject= {}, // oject that needs to be converted to JSON
value1 = { topic: "someText1", status: "0", action: "1", comment: "someComment1" }, // values of Map
value2 = { topic: "someText2", status: "0", action: "0", comment: "someComment2" },
value3 = { topic: "someText3", status: "1", action: "1", comment: "someComment3" };
```

**Point 2:** populating Map 
*// key of map is concatenation of various attributes from web page, separated by **|***

```
map.set('release|attachment|license1|topic1', value1);
map.set('release|attachment|license1|topic2', value1);
map.set('release1|attachment1|license1|topic1', value1);
map.set('release1|attachment1|license2|topic2', value2);
map.set('release1|attachment1|license3|topic3', value3);
map.set('release2|attachment2|license2|topic2', value2);
map.set('release2|attachment2|license2|topic3', value2);
```

**Point 3:** iterating map and populating jsonObject

```
for (const [key, values] of map) {
    setPath(jsonObject, key.split('|'), values);
}
function setPath(obj, [...keys], item) {
    keys.pop(); // removing topic
    const last = keys.pop();
    keys.reduce((r, a) => r[a] = r[a] || {}, obj)[last] =  [item];
}
```

**Point 4:** current output [`console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));`]

```
{
  "release": {
    "attachment": {
      "license1": [
        {
          "topic": "someText2",
          "status": "0",
          "action": "0",
          "comment": "someComment2"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "release1": {
    "attachment1": {
      "license1": [
        {
          "topic": "someText1",
          "status": "0",
          "action": "1",
          "comment": "someComment1"
        }
      ],
      "license2": [
        {
          "topic": "someText2",
          "status": "0",
          "action": "0",
          "comment": "someComment2"
        }
      ],
      "license3": [
        {
          "topic": "someText3",
          "status": "1",
          "action": "1",
          "comment": "someComment3"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "release2": {
    "attachment2": {
      "license2": [
        {
          "topic": "someText3",
          "status": "1",
          "action": "1",
          "comment": "someComment3"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Point 5:** expected output (jsonObject)

```
{
  "release": {
    "attachment": {
      "license1": [
        {
          "topic": "someText1", // ^^ This object is missing in current output.
          "status": "0",
          "action": "1",
          "comment": "someComment1"
        },
        {
          "topic": "someText2",
          "status": "0",
          "action": "0",
          "comment": "someComment2"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "release1": {
    "attachment1": {
      "license1": [
        {
          "topic": "someText1",
          "status": "0",
          "action": "1",
          "comment": "someComment1"
        }
      ],
      "license2": [
        {
          "topic": "someText2",
          "status": "0",
          "action": "0",
          "comment": "someComment2"
        }
      ],
      "license3": [
        {
          "topic": "someText3",
          "status": "1",
          "action": "1",
          "comment": "someComment3"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "release2": {
    "attachment2": {
      "license2": [
        {
          "topic": "someText2", // ^^ This object is missing in current output.
          "status": "0",
          "action": "0",
          "comment": "someComment2"
        },
        {
          "topic": "someText3",
          "status": "1",
          "action": "1",
          "comment": "someComment3"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

^^ I want to have array of objects in `jsonObject`.

Can someone help me with tweak needs to be done in `setPath` function in **Point 3** to obtain expected result?

PS: I know that I have asked similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57228659/convert-multi-value-mapstring-object-to-json-in-javascript).

Comment: Are you sure you want to do `map.set('release|attachment|license1|topic1', value1);` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the license arrays instead of just appending the new items.

Change this line

```js
keys.reduce((r, a) => r[a] = r[a] || {}, obj)[last] =  [item];
```

to this

```js
const target = keys.reduce((r, a) => r[a] = r[a] || {}, obj);
(target[last] = target[last] || []).push(item);
```